# Firebase Realtime Database still remain void while using app. How is it possible? It's very strange

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This are the rules on my Firebase Realtime Database:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

RegisterActivity.java

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mUserName, mEmail, mPassword;
    private Button registerBtn;
    private TextView toLogin;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private ImageView mImage;

    // Firebase stuff
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        setupUI();

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        registerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String userName = mUserName.getText().toString();
                String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = mPassword.getText().toString();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(userName)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Username is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Email is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Password is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if(userName.length() < 4) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Username too short", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Valid email address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if(password.length() < 8) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Password must contain at least 8 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                userRegister(email, password);
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuActivity.class));
                finish();

            }
        });

        toLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    private void userRegister(String email, String password) {

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegisterActivity.this,
                R.style.AppTheme_Dark_Dialog);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Creating account...");
        progressDialog.show();


        //register user in firebase
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()) {

                    User user = new User(email, password);
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users")
                            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                            .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "User successful created",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Failed to register",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Error! " +
                            task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private void setupUI() {
        mImage = findViewById(R.id.image);
        mUserName = findViewById(R.id.userName_register);
        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.email_register);
        mPassword = findViewById(R.id.password_register);
        registerBtn = findViewById(R.id.register_button);
        toLogin = findViewById(R.id.toLogin);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_register);
    }

}
```

User.java

```
public class User {

    public String userName, email, password;

    public User() {    }

    public User(String email, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User(String userName, String email, String password) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

I have tried many things found on web but none have worked and nothing changes, it still remain void. I'm very desperate guys. Am I forgetting to add something? Unfortunately I'm new in Android and Firebase. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a lot going on in this code, and Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger. If you run this code in a debugger, set breakpoints on all lines where you expect certain behavior, which line is the first one that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: The issue is that the console doesn't report no errors and using the debugger and putting the breakpoints, it completely skips those lines of code

Comment: Again: we have no way of knowing what "those lines of code" are unless you tell us. Where did you place a breakpoint? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? I highly recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as it increases the chances we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup the application by downloading the *google-services.json* from Firebase console and putting it in the Android Studio project?

Also, did you add your app's signature to the allowed apps in Firebase console?

Refer to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

Comment: Yes, I added the google-services.json file and all necessary dependencies